# how can I fix permission denied error while trying to install pyrebase

Tags: python, pip

When I try to install pyrebase i get this error message.

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:
>   /Users/myname/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/google/api

what can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `sudo` for linux or on windows run your command prompt as administrator

```
sudo pip install pyrebase
```

Answer (score 1):

You need root/Administrator privileges.

On linux use sudo before command and on Windows you can open a command prompt as administrator by right clicking it and selecting run as administrator.