# How to install EbaySDK on python on Mac

Tags: python, sdk, pip, ebay-sdk

I'm trying to install `EbaySDK` for Mac using Python but its not working. I have tried to follow [this](https://github.com/timotheus/ebaysdk-python/blob/master/INSTALL), but doesn't seem like I can use `yum` or `apt-get` for Mac. I also tried to use PIP but apparently need `BeautifulSoup4` and it fails:

followed steps:

- have python & pycharm environment installed
- have pip installed
- tried pip install beautifulsoup4 and get below error message
- when trying to import EbaySDk its not found. I really need help with this guys!

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-9.0.1-py2.7.egg/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/beautifulsoup4-4.6.0.dist-info'
```

Comment: May be you don't have write access in that directory.

Comment: have you tried sudo?

Comment: I looked into write access issues and sudo bit that didnt work either. I tried: sudo easy_install python setup.py install and got the following error:

error: Could not find suitable distribution for Requirement.parse('setup.py')

even though that file does exist in the location it checked

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can I fix permission denied error while trying to install pyrebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46133715/how-can-i-fix-permission-denied-error-while-trying-to-install-pyrebase)

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute the following:

```
sudo easy_install ebaysdk
```

This will install the correct package