# Pip having trying to uninstall appdirs while trying to install requirements.txt when deploying to pythonanywhere

Tags: django, pip, pythonanywhere

I am trying to deploy my project on pythonanywhere. I have created my virtualenv and activated it but when I try to

```
"pip install -r requirements.txt"
```

it says

```
"Found existing installation: appdirs1.4.2 Uninstalling appdirs-1.4.2:"
```

and then gets a permission denied error.

What's going on and how do I fix it?

Full error in bpaste: https://bpaste.net/show/a7394c84c672

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how can I fix permission denied error while trying to install pyrebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46133715/how-can-i-fix-permission-denied-error-while-trying-to-install-pyrebase)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pip found `appdirs-1.4.2` and gonna uninstall it and replace with `appdirs-1.4.3` but failed on uninstallation — you don't have write access to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/`. Run with `sudo`:

```
sudo pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: It doesn't look like I can use sudo in pythonanywhere console

"sudo: unknown user: root
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin"

Comment: Then use `su`. Or `pip install --user`. Or `virtualenv`.

Comment: Thank you. "pip install --user -r requirements.txt" worked

Comment: Actually, this causes problems down the road. The right way to do this is to put your virtualenv here
"mkvirtualenv --python=/usr/bin/python2.7 myvirtualenv"